ROS2 cpp file, colcon build is getting failed all the time
I got the following error:
ros2_ws$ colcon build --packages-select my_cpp_pkg Starting >>> my_cpp_pkg --- stderr: my_cpp_pkg
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function _start': (.text+0x1b): undefined reference to main' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpp_node.dir/build.make:151: cpp_node] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:137: CMakeFiles/cpp_node.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
Failed <<< my_cpp_pkg [0.89s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 0 packages finished [1.68s] 1 package failed: my_cpp_pkg
1 package had stderr output: my_cpp_pkg

and below is my CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(my_cpp_pkg)

#default to c++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)



add_executable(cpp_node src/my_first_node.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(cpp_node rclcpp)

install(TARGETS 
  cpp_node
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)


ament_package()

I was trying to run a cpp node but I guess cmake list was creating problems.

Is this supposed to build a library or an executable? An executable has to have a main function as the starting point, and the builder seems to be looking for that. So perhaps incorrect build options, or a function missing?

I was following a course on udemy, I did same as he did but I was getting this error.  It had a main function in the .cpp file but error was showing in cmake or may be some other which I didn't understand, I can share whole ss of the programs.

The error message indicates that c++ linker does not succeed in linking your executable. From the error message, you can see that the c++ linker fails to link your program into a valid executable, because it can not find the main function of your program.
The actual issue has nothing to do with colcon or your CMakeLists.txt file. The issue is that your src/my_first_node.cpp file does not provide a main function.
If you want to know more about c++ main functions, you can take a look at cppreference main function
